# MySQL Query conditional find nth element in column string

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table setup where one column's values are a string of comma-separated True/False values (1s or 0s). For example, in the column, one field's value may be "0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0" and another may be "1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0" (note: these are NOT 9 separate columns, but a string in one column).  I need to QUERY the MySQL table for elements that are "true"(1) for the "nth element" of that column's value/string.

So, if I was looking for rows, with a specific column, where the 3rd element of the column's value was 1, it would produce a list of results.  So, in this case, I would only be searching for "1" in the fth place (12345 = X,X,X...) of the string (X,X,1,X,X,X,X,X,X,X). How can I query this?

This is a **crude example** of what I am trying to do ...

```
"SELECT tfcolumn FROM mytable WHERE substr({tfcolumn}, 0, 5)=1"
```

{tfcolumn} represents the column value
5 represents the 5th position of the string
=1 represents what I need that position to equal to.

Please help. Thanks

Comment: This is an example of very very poor database design.  Things that are supposed to be very easy to do become very complicated because of the messed up design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Once you put a serialized data type into a column in SQL (like comma separated lists, or JSON objects) you are preventing yourself from performing any query on the data in those columns. You have to pull the data in a different way and then use a program like python, VB, etc to get the comma separated values you are looking for.

Unless you want to deal with trying to make [this mess of a query work...](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1101816/How-to-Query-Comma-Seperated-Value-Column-in-SQL)
**I would recommend changing your table structure before it's too late.** Although it is possible, it is not optimized in a format that a DBMS recognizes. Because of that the DBMS will spend a significant amount of time going through every record to parse the csv values which is something that it was not meant to be doing. Doing the query in SQL will take as much time (if not more time) than just pulling all the records and searching with a tool that can do it properly.

Comment: That makes sense. I thought using the array/string for the values would be easier for certain things, but I see your point. I don't want to have to run through EVERY ROW to try and find the element I need. I may use your suggestion and just create a column for each item in the string/array.

Comment: One thing you could consider is `SELECT ... WHERE myField LIKE "%,%,%,%,1,%"`. Although not as optimized as having a column for the fields you want to sort by it would work

Comment: I just restructured the table - built a page to display all the rows, and then used an "update" query (and a little PHP to break apart the old column) to fill in all the new columns.

Answer (score 0):

If the column contains values exactly like the ones you posted, then the `Nth` element is at the `2 * N - 1` position in the comma separated list.
So do this:

```
SELECT tfcolumn 
FROM tablename 
WHERE substr(tfcolumn, 2 * 5 - 1, 1) = '1'
```

Replace 5 with the index that you search for.
See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hWJJQpbvoGEE46D9hmMHWW/0).
Or remove all commas and get the `Nth` char:

```
SELECT tfcolumn 
FROM tablename 
WHERE substr(replace(tfcolumn, ',', ''), 5, 1) = '1'
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hWJJQpbvoGEE46D9hmMHWW/2).

Comment: Can you really use a php function inside a query? I threw up my crude example because I thought it could be used just to show an example....  But, I think I will run into memory/processing issues later on as the table grows (since every row will have to run through the process to find the appropriate rows...).  Will probably need to find another solution...

Comment: What do you mean? What php function?

Comment: substr() and replace() are functions of PHP. The query is technically just a string you use to access MySQL (as far as my limited understand goes).

Comment: `substr()` and `replace()` are functions of MySql: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this

if substring_index(substring_index('0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0',',',3),',',-1)='1'

The first argument can be your column name. The second argument (',') tells the function that the string is comma-separated. The third argument takes the first 3 elements of the string. So, the output of inner substring_index is '0,1,0'.
The outer substring_index has -1 as the last argment. So, it starts counting in reverse direction & takes only 1 element starting from right.
For example, if the value in a particular row is '2,682,7003,14,185', then the value of substring_index(substring_index('2,682,7003,14,185',',',3),',',-1) is '7003'.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).